Would a masterair ma612 stealth argb be able to cool a 12900t? I want to upgrade but dont wanna upgrade my case n stuff (have a carbide seiries 100r)
I have the money to upgrade to a 12900t but am sceptical about it even though it is a relatively low wattage cpu. I dont want to lose money having to get an aio and a new case, I also have done a bios update on my b660 pro rs and could go to 13th gen intel so yea so idk.
